# Generate a keystore after updating bundle id

Tags: android, react-native, keystore

Recently, I've updated Android bundle id. Is it required to generate a new release keystore file after that?

The main concern is that Google Sign In no longer works with the following error: `DEVELOPER_ERROR`. The app is already available in stores and issue is reproducible only after downloading a build from it. Works perfectly locally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to create new release keystore file if you have changed android package name

If google sign in is not working in the build available on the play store only than please add release signin key in firebase developer console

1. Go to the Google Play console and copy SHA-1 and SHA-256 key from Release -> Setup -> App Integrity
2. Add this keys in firebase develop console -> your android app -> SHA certificate fingerprints